# Send audio from USB port to built-in microphone (Mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, audio, core-audio, loopback

I have some audio troubles, so I want to send the input audio that comes from my USB port to my built-in microphone.

I would like to do it using System preferences and MIDI Setup but I'm open-minded to other kind of solutions.

I'll love the angel that will respond writing some kind of code, C, C++...I'm a young programmer so I'm not so advanced but I'll try hard to understand it because I would like to create my own script/software.

Or, at least, I appreciate also if someone will tell me where I should search for better answers (maybe other sites I don't know).

Comment: I think [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) is still the most reliable way of routing audio internally. [Catalina support is still ongoing](https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/issues/93)

Comment: I tried using Soundflower, I created a multi-output devices but it still wasn't working :(

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by sending audio to the microphone? What would you like to do with the audio?

Comment: After you have created an aggregate device, remember that you will have to also set whatever software you are using to listen to that device as input. @sbooth is correct, you don’t _send data to the microphone_, but rather you create a new input and route audio to it.

Comment: @sbooth I have a game capture device (that has an HDMI cable as input) mounted on my USB port (output). From the MIDI audio setup I see it mounted (its name is FHD) and I see it also in System preferences -> audio. But the audio is stuck somewhere because I can't hear it! When I insert the capture device in my USB port I hear nothing so I want to send the audio that comes from the capture device (stuck somewhere) to the Mac built-in microphone, or Desktop...I want to hear the sound from HDMI cable! I tried creating a multi-output device(MIDI) with Soundflower and the device but nothing...

Comment: @fdcpp Software isn't optimised for Mac, it was developed for Windows...In fact Windows users have the option to send the audio that comes from the capture device to their Desktop so they can hear it from headphones, Mac users don't have it, bad developers :( ...I'm trying to bypass this issue using Soundflower and currently I'm using IshowU audio capture ( I heard that the develop of Soundflower is stopped so I'm using this that's similar) but it doesn't work...Now I found an application, it's name is loopback and it works fine but is too expensive...

Comment: Where is the audio going to the FHD coming from? Is it also coming from your Mac or from some external device? I am not sure if your want to route audio from your Mac to the FHD and also to your Mac (split the output) or route audio coming in from the FHD to your Mac's output.